# Keep first word of Python string?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of full names, like:

```
names : ["Katie von Martin", "Bob Austin Marley", "John Travolta", "Josh Hartnett"]
```

What would a function to split each string and retain only the first word look like?

```
def keepFirstName():
    for name in names:
        ????
```

Comment: What if the first name is more than one word long ?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest would be:

```
def first_names(names):
    for name in names:
        yield name.split()[0]
```

e.g.

```
>>> print list(first_names(["Katie von Martin", "Bob Austin Marley", "John Travolta", "Josh Hartnett"]))
['Katie', 'Bob', 'John', 'Josh']
```

There are a few circumstances where you may not want to split the string if you just want the first word ... e.g. if the strings are *REALLY* long.  In that case, you can use `str.find` to get the location of the first space in the string and then you can slice up to that point to give you only the first name:

```
>>> def first_names(names):
...     for name in names:
...         idx = name.find(' ')
...         yield name[:idx] if idx > 0 else name
... 
>>> print list(first_names(["Katie von Martin", "Bob Austin Marley", "John Travolta", "Josh Hartnett"]))
['Katie', 'Bob', 'John', 'Josh']
```

However, in practice, this is almost never necessary.

Comment: I'd change the name to something more intuitive if you're going to make it a generator, e.g. `firstNames`, so statements like `for name in firstNames([...])` are more readable.

Comment: @HenryKeiter -- fair enough.  If I'm going to change the name anyway, might as well go with `first_names` to make PEP 8 happy :)

Comment: @mgilson Good catch! You should change the names in the example calls as well, though ;)

Comment: As a side note, I've always wished for a `str.split` that returns a generator object...

Comment: @HenryKeiter -- I knew I was forgetting something!

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, this will give you the first words:

```
>>> names = ["Katie von Martin", "Bob Austin Marley", "John Travolta", "Josh Hartnett"]
>>> first_words = [words.split()[0] for words in names]
>>> print first_words 

['Katie', 'Bob', 'John', 'Josh']
```

Answer (score 1):

To retain it and store it in a list,

```
b=[]
for i in names:
    b.append(i.split()[0])
```

The list b contains the first names